# Find file with name recursively in parent directories in Go

Tags: go, recursion

I have a directory:

```
basepath + /my/sub/directory
```

In that subdirectory, I have multiple instances of a file with name `file.json`

Example:

```
my/file.json
my/sub/file.json
my/sub/directory/file.json
```

What I want to do is use the full directory path and walk BACK up the file tree until I hit the `basepath` and find all the filepaths for the `file.json`

I looked at `filepath.Walk` but that seems to go downwards through the directory tree, not upwards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way you can walk backwards and read each `file.json` along the way.

> Example project directory structure:

```
./
  - main.go
  ./my
    - file.json > {"location": "/my"}
    ./my/sub
      - file.json > {"location": "/my/sub"}
      ./my/sub/dir
        - file.json > {"location": "/my/sub/dir"}
```

---

> main.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "path/filepath"
)

func main() {
    basePath := "./"
    targetPath := basePath + "my/sub/dir"
    fileName := "file.json"

    for {
        rel, _ := filepath.Rel(basePath, targetPath)

        // Exit the loop once we reach the basePath.
        if rel == "." {
            break
        }

        // Simple file reading logic.
        dat, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fmt.Sprintf("%v/%v", targetPath, fileName))
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(string(dat))

        // Going up!
        targetPath += "/.."
    }

}
```

---

> Output:

```
{ "location": "/my/sub/dir" }
{ "location": "/my/sub" }
{ "location": "/my" }
```

*Hope you find this approach useful.*